# Getting Orders from Customer

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, customer, collection, magento-1

If I have a customer object, what would be the best/fastest way to get a list of orders placed by that customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with Resource Model

```
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', CUSTOMER_ID_HERE)
        //If customer is already logged in, use below line
        //->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($orders->getData());
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: May I ask why you prefer to use `Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')` instead of `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()`?

Comment: No big reason, but I think when you use `sales/order`, it calls resource model (`sales/order_collection`) in background, that we did directly

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
          ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $customer->getEmail());
```

Comment: May I ask why you prefer to use `Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')` instead of `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()`?

Comment: @Skytiger no particular reason it's exactly the same